# Credit Memo in Magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, php-5.4, creditmemo, refund

I have stuck creating credit memo in magento.

**Assumption : I want to refund $10 to Customer ( Refund Offline = $10).**

1) Actually I have Placed an Order with One Item 1005 (Price 1000 + 5 Tax & Handling).

2) Created Invoice for this Order.

3) I was fallow the below steps to Creating Credit Memo

I) I have put the 0 to Qty to Refund and hit the Update Qty's button.

II) And entered $990 on Adjustment Fee

III) Again put the 1 to Qty to Refund and hit the Update Qty's button,

IV) Now Grand Total is $10

4) Finally I hit the Refund Offline button.

Here the Refund Amount is $10 right?

But it is refunding $1000.

Is it my procedure is right or I went wrong?

if it is wrong How can I do this through Offline?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this:

- Qty to refund: 0
- Refund shipping: fill this in if applicable
- Adjustment refund: 10
- Click refund offline

Then you will have refunded 10 dollar. Keep in mind that Qty to refund is still 0 on submitting.